# TypeError: _functions.default.config is not a function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, react-native-firebase

I have deployed some environment variables using Firebase Cloud Functions following [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env).

I am using React Native Firebase and want to access the environment variables. In the Firebase docs it says you can access the variables in the following way:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const request = require('request-promise');

exports.userCreated = functions.database.ref('/users/{id}').onWrite(event => {
  let email = event.data.child('email').val();

  return request({
    url: 'https://someservice.com/api/some/call',
    headers: {
      'X-Client-ID': functions.config().someservice.id,
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${functions.config().someservice.key}`
    },
    body: {email: email}
  });
});
```

In the [React Native Firebase docs](https://rnfirebase.io/functions/usage), it says import and use Firebase functions like this:

```js
import functions from '@react-native-firebase/functions';

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    functions()
      .httpsCallable('listProducts')()
      .then(response => {
        setProducts(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);
```

Notice the difference in import.

My code is as follows:

```js
import functions from '@react-native-firebase/functions';

const id = functions.config().xyz.id;
const key = functions.config().xyz.key;
```

I am getting an error thrown which is:

`TypeError: _functions.default.config is not a function`

All packages seem to be installed correctly - my versions are as follows:

```
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^6.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^6.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/functions": "^7.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^6.3.0",
```

Where am I going wrong and how can the Firebase Cloud Functions be combined with React Native Firebase to obtain deployed environment variables?

#### Update

I have updated all RNFB packages to v 7.1.0 but am still having the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://rnfirebase.io/functions/usage) the `@react-native-firebase/functions` module "provides the functionality to directly trigger deployed [HTTPS Callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)".

In other words, this module is used to call, **from your front-end**, some Cloud Functions which are executed **in the back-end**, in Firebase/Google Cloud infrastructure.

On the other hand, retrieving some Cloud Function environment variables can only be done **in the Cloud Function, in the back-end**.

So you cannot use `functions.config()` in your React code, which is executed in the front-end. You can only do that in the Cloud Function code, executed in the back-end.

---

What you could do, in the callable Cloud Function, is [to return to the front-end](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result) (the caller, or consumer) the environment variables retrieved in the Cloud Function.

Something along the following lines:

### Callable Cloud Function

```
exports.getEnvVariable = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const serviceId = functions.config().someservice.id;

  return { serviceId };
});
```

### React Front-end

```
import functions from '@react-native-firebase/functions';

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    functions()
      .httpsCallable('getEnvVariable')()
      .then(response => {
         const serviceId = response.data.serviceId;
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Ok thanks very much, I understand. I'm going to try this, but another question entirely - is this a secure way to access API keys for my react native app?

Comment: "is this a secure way to access API keys for my react native app?" -> What do you exactly mean? I would suggest you ask a new question, with all the details, as it  seems this is somehow a different question.

Comment: Yes you're right of course - I'm just thinking that if this is not a good way to access API keys (I thought this would be a good / correct approach) then there is no point in trying it. Normally with a web application API keys would be stored as env variables in the platform you deploy to, but as this is an app, I'm not deploying it.

Comment: API Keys (https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object) are totally different from configuration variables used in a Cloud Function.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. I will ask a new question about how to do this. What I'm looking to do is store API keys for an API that are completely unrelated to Firebase.

Comment: It seems this something totally independent from Firebase and shall be done in React. I cannot help you on that, sorry!